# is ist possible to combine lazarus forms and python procedures to an deliverable application?

Tags: python, lazarus

At the moment I have to develop some python tools, because nearly every software I use (QGIS, FreeCAD, Gimp, probably my toothbrush ...) has a python interface.

I would like to write lazarus applications (with button, edits and all the nice components), that uses my python routines in the background and show the results in lazarus.

Is there a way?

Comment: Why not do it all in Python. Plenty of decent UI tooling for Python. Of course you can interact with Python by embedding, but it will make the project more complex.

Comment: Cause lazarus is much more comfortable and much easier to maintain for me

Comment: And what about the comfort of the Python interop? You seem to be neglecting that.

Comment: If I need a ball I buy a ball, if I need an apple I buy an apple. I know, I could play football with an apple, but what for? For me the perfect tool to build maintainable user Inferfaces is lazarus, the flexibility of python is perfect for the hard work. So I would like to combine the benefits.

Comment: Again, you are ignoring the comfort, or discomfort as it will be, of the interop. Your analogy is too simplistic. Perhaps it will be easier overall. But you need to evaluate how awkward the interop is first.

Comment: If I need a window with 2 Edits, a pagecontrol with 2 Tabs, an image on each of it and a textbox with a splitter at the end of the window, all reacting in a nice way, a main Menu with 3 Items and the same popup with 2 Items, so I need about 5 Minutes to design this. The code at the end is small, so that I can extend this within 2 further minutes, if I need a progressbar, a font- open- dialog and a panel with 2 buttons. At the end I have an executable, that without any installation runs on every computer of my associates. This is the ball! Maybe it is too awkward, but I think it would be worth

Comment: Not really. You need to have python installed. And you need to interop with it.

Comment: I know, but it is easy for me to make sure python is installed. But w/o a comfortable user interface many useful tools can not be delivered.

Comment: This is such a bizarre conversation. The subject of the question, how to interop with Python, you seem to think this can be done with no effort. So why even ask if it is trivial?

Comment: I never spoke about no effort, I only told that I think it is the effort worth.

Comment: And if you could tell me, how to interop, so I could decide, whether it is better to combine or not. Any ideas?

Comment: If you already know that it's worth the effort then you already know how much effort it is and you need nothing from us.

Comment: Hi Rudy, long times ago we met @ delphi newsgroup, nice to hear from you. There are many interfaces, that easy can be used by python (QGIS, PyCAD ...) It would be much harder to connect to it with Object Pascal. And some things as the easy using of dictionaries, lists, lists of lists and so on are very comfortable. But at least for me python is a write only language. Code longer than 20 lines should not be written in pythen for my opinion ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example at the Lazarus forum how to use the Python for Lazarus package. From Lazarus Online Package Manager it installs automatically.

https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,43557.msg305118.html#msg305118

Set PythonEngine.IO to PythonGUIInputOutput, then choose a control for PythonGUIInputOutput.Output to show data and your good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use

https://github.com/pyscripter/python4delphi

that is a binding between the two.

There is also always available the possibility of implementing a web server with python and publish its services on http for use from lazarus.

Note however that if what you want is a GUI then Qt (using PyQt or PySide) is a very complete GUI library with a very good binding for Python... it has all the widgets you can imagine, and then some more.
In that case all the code you write is in Python.

Comment: Python has its benefits, of course, but to build GUIs and executables Lazarus is much better in my opinion. The package you mentioned seems to be developed for Delphi VCL, but I will try, maybe it works with lazarus too!

Comment: @am2: The caption for *python4delphi* says: *"Free components that wrap up Python into Delphi and Lazarus (FPC)"*. So while it may originally have been developed for *Delphi*, it seems to be useable with *FPC/Lazarus* too.

Comment: @6502: but that seems to work the other way, i.e. it lets you script your applications with Python. He wants to write plugins for the program he mentions, and these plugins are Python (makes sense, programs like Gimp or Inkscape, etc. have Python interfaces). He only wants to use Lazarus for the GUI part. Not sure if it works that way around too.